# Flutter Firebase Email Passwordless login - Link giving error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a flutter app in which I'm trying to use firebase Email passwordless sign in. The sending part is working, but when I open the link I get an error:

[image: email sign in link canHandleCodeInApp error]

The handleCodeInApp parameter in the actioncode settings is true however.

```
_firebaseAuth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
  email: email.value,
  actionCodeSettings: firebase_auth.ActionCodeSettings(
    url: uri.toString(),
    iOSBundleId: "myPackageName",
    androidPackageName: "myPackageName",
    androidMinimumVersion: '0',
    androidInstallApp: false,
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    dynamicLinkDomain: "myPackageName",
  ),
);
```

The Uri gets created here:

```
DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
  uriPrefix: 'https://myRegisteredDomain',
  link: Uri.parse('https://myRegisteredDomain'),
  androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
    packageName: 'myPackageName',
    minimumVersion: 0,
  ),
  iosParameters: IosParameters(
    bundleId: 'myPackageName',
    minimumVersion: '0',
  ),
);
return await parameters.buildUrl();
```

Intent filter is set up as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="myRegisteredDomain" android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:host="myRegisteredDomain" android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

In firebase I have set up the domain as needed and it has been whitelisted. At this point I have no idea why I'm even getting this error as handleCodeInApp is set to true. I can only guess that my link is incorrect in some way, but I wouldn't know where I set it up wrong. If anyone knows where I went wrong or you need additional information, please tell me.

**Solution**

1. The Uri generated using the DynamicLinkParameters does not work. Just use a string like: "https://PROJECT.page.link". This solved the error I was getting.
2. The isSignInWithEmailLink check from FirebaseAuth isn't working correctly with version ^0.20.0+1, which I was using. Reference https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4711#issuecomment-762323661 on how to fix this. After this fix I can now use Passwordless sign in as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow Firebase Email Link Authentication example guide at FlutterFire

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#email-link-authentication

It works like a charm.

Comment: Going through the tutorial learned I should just get rid of the entire creating an Uri using DynamicLinkParameters. Simply put in the uri yourself as shown in the linked tutorial.
Another thing I discovered is that the whole isSignInWithEmailLink check from the tutorial doesn't work with firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1. See https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4711#issuecomment-762323661

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/ keep the link handy will give the list of working firebase packages together

Comment: I looked at the tutorial above, but am not sure what is the right way to read the `emailLink` parameter. I'm doing this, right in my main.dart `import 'dart:html' as html;
final String launch_url = html.window.location.href; ` but that feels hacky and I'm assuming will not work on mobile. suggestions?